# How to loop through newline separated json line by line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file in my project that looks like this:

```
{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}}
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}}
{"_id":1283378,"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}}
```

I'm not sure how to loop through each line to put it in an array. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you able to open the file and read it in?

Comment: So you want to take an invalid structure and turn it into an Array of objects. Load the file, split new lines, join with comma, wrap with `[` and `]`, and JSON.parse it. OR fix it so it is valid to start and not have to deal with that.

Comment: @epascarello Encapsulating one format in another is very common.  Line-delimited JSON streams are extremely common.  It's probably the best, most straightforward way to handle a stream of JSON objects.  Would you rather have an infinitely sized never ending array and buffer data into memory forever?  Would you rather hack the parser or implement a streaming parser?  There's nothing wrong with line-delimited JSON as long as you know what you're doing and have a good use case for it.

Comment: @Brad sounds like there is not a good use case for this if OP needs it in an array. ;)

Comment: You need some way of parsing this as a javascript object. If you're using a backend like node try using `fs` if you're using javascript in the browser, you'll have to use some ajax request.

Comment: @richbai90 What?  The file system and AJAX have absolutely nothing to do with parsing anything....

Comment: @Brad the OP said the JSON was in a file, therefore to get it into a javascript object he'll have to get it out of the file first. That's where my comment came from. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 9):

Split on new lines, join with comma, wrap it with brackets, and parse it.

```js
var str = `{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}}
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}}
{"_id":1283378,"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}}`

var lines = str.split(/\n/);
var wrapped = "[" + lines.join(",") + "]";
var obj = JSON.parse(wrapped);

console.log(obj);
```

Better solution, fix whatever gives you that format to give you the correct structure to start out with.

Answer (score 7):

What about using map properly?

```js
var myVar = `{"_id":707860,"name":"Hurzuf","country":"UA","coord":{"lon":34.283333,"lat":44.549999}}
{"_id":519188,"name":"Novinki","country":"RU","coord":{"lon":37.666668,"lat":55.683334}}
{"_id":1283378,"name":"Gorkhā","country":"NP","coord":{"lon":84.633331,"lat":28}}`;

var myArray = myVar.split('\n').map(JSON.parse);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: The one above that uses the map, is actually creating a new array, copying the array outside of the map and then returning that one. It defeats the full purpose of the map, since the map exists because it returns the changed data. For not using the returned data, then one should use a forEach or a for cycle.

Comment: About the one that uses the join, its probably more optimized since it parses the json in one go instead of per each element.  My post was mainly to warn about the improper use of the map.